# c# Converting a type to a generic

Tags: c#, .net, generics, dependency-injection, unity-container

I'm trying to consolidate some code in an old .NET 4.0 project using `UnityContainer` for DI.

I have the following list of registrations, which are lazy loaded, with a constructor injection in a Unity registry:

```
public class MyRegistry : UnityRegistry
{
    public MyRegistry()
    {
        Register(GetDataAccessInjectionFactory<AddressProviderBase>());
        Register(GetDataAccessInjectionFactory<CustomerProviderBase>());
        // Hundreds of these registrations..... manually maintained... urrgh
        // I want to scan for them instead
    }
    
    private Func<IUnityContainer, T> GetDataAccessInjectionFactory<T>() where T : class
    {
        return c => DataAccessProvider<T>.GetDataAccess(c.Resolve<ITenantCodeProvider>());
    }
}
```

The `DataAccessProvider` is just a cached concurrent dictionary in order to switch database connection based on the tenant. It looks like this:

```
public class DataAccessProvider<T> where T : class
{
    public static T GetDataAccess(ITenantCodeProvider tenantCodeProvider)
    {
        // ... implementation
    }
}
```

I'm trying to replace them with a single `UnityContainer` scan using a [custom convention](https://github.com/thedersen/UnityConfiguration/blob/a91e69fbe7cfdd3c72941303e38f728577f7502d/src/UnityConfiguration.Tests/CustomConventionTests.cs):

```
Scan(scan =>
{
    scan.With<CustomProviderBaseConvention>();
    scan.AssemblyContaining<AddressProviderBase>();
});
```

However, the IAssemblyScannerConvention interface provides me with this:

```
public class CustomProviderBasesConvention : IAssemblyScannerConvention
{
    // required interface
    void IAssemblyScannerConvention.Process(Type type, IUnityRegistry registry)
    {
        // this "type" obviously won't work. Do I need reflection here?
        registry.Register(GetDataAccessInjectionFactory<type>());
    }

    public Func<IUnityContainer, T> GetDataAccessInjectionFactory<T>() where T : class
    {
        return c => DataAccessProvider<T>.GetDataAccess(c.Resolve<ITenantCodeProvider>());
    }
}
```

This is more of a generics / typing issue than something to do with Unity DI. Any pointers about how to replace the hundreds of manually added and maintained `ProviderBase` registrations would be most welcomed.

Even using reflection, I end up with the same problem, that I can't cast the result:

```
public class CustomProviderBasesConvention : IAssemblyScannerConvention
{
    void IAssemblyScannerConvention.Process(Type type, IUnityRegistry registry)
    {
        MethodInfo method = typeof(DataAccessProvider<>).GetMethod("GetDataAccess", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
        MethodInfo generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(type);
        // cast needs a type
        var factory = (Func<IUnityContainer, ????>)generic.Invoke(this, null);
        registry.Register(factory);
    }

    public Func<IUnityContainer, T> GetDataAccessInjectionFactory<T>() where T : class
    {
        return c => DataAccessProvider<T>.GetDataAccess(c.Resolve<ITenantCodeProvider>());
    }
}
```

I have the same problem if I loop through the assembly types:

```
var assembly = typeof(AddressProviderBase).Assembly;
var types = assembly.GetTypes().Where(x => x.FullName.EndsWith("ProviderBase")).ToList();
foreach(var t in types)
{
    MethodInfo method = typeof(DataAccessProvider<>).GetMethod("GetDataAccess", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
    MethodInfo generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(t);
    Register((Func<IUnityContainer, ??>)generic.Invoke(this, null));
}
```

Comment: To do this `GetDataAccessInjectionFactory<type>` you can try this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/232535/how-do-i-use-reflection-to-call-a-generic-method.

Comment: @Serg see update, even then I can't cast the result post invoke.

Comment: What version of `Unity` and `UnityConfiguration` are you using?

Comment: @Hank very old. 2.1.505.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Unity itself may have the better way to do this, but if we want to go in the reflection way, then we can do the following.

```
public class CustomProviderBasesConvention : IAssemblyScannerConvention
{
    void IAssemblyScannerConvention.Process(Type type, IUnityRegistry registry)
    {
        var method = typeof(CustomProviderBasesConvention).GetMethod(nameof(Helper),
                            BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        var generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(type);
        generic.Invoke(this, new[] { registry });
    }
    
    private void Helper<T>(IUnityRegistry registry) where T : class
    {
        var factory = GetDataAccessInjectionFactory<T>();
        registry.Register(factory);

    }
    public Func<IUnityContainer, T> GetDataAccessInjectionFactory<T>() where T : class
    {
        return c => DataAccessProvider<T>.GetDataAccess(c.Resolve<ITenantCodeProvider>());
    }
}
```

The problem in the assemble scan code may be solved with exactly the same way with generic `Helper` function.

Comment: That is awesome! You shifted the problem. What a great solution. Thank you.